# Multilevel menu bar using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've tried the following code in creating a multilevel menu bar using angular material. But it seems like routing is not working as expected. Does anyone have an idea on what's went wrong here or any reason that causes this problem?

nav.component.html

```
check `routerlink` path whatever u mention it doesn't work go with a method

<a mat-list-item routerLinkActive="active" class="navAd-link" [routerLink]="['/students']" (click)="navAd.toggle()">
    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>group</mat-icon>
    <span class="title" mat-line>Students</span>
</a>
```

routes.ts

```
import { StudentsComponent } from './Students/Students.component';
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'students', component: StudentsComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: 'students', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

Comment: error information? Or if possible then provide Stackblitz so anyone can reproduce issue

Comment: **Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.**   Got this when I inspected it. No other errors displayed under problems

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz?>

Comment: students !== Students

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for the answer. If yes and for new viewers, then I have created a plugin for Angular which creates a Multilevel menu. Now you can convert this multilevel menu to Accordion as well, for example, Check [this example](https://multilevel-menu-demo.web.app/pages/layout-variations/demo-three).

Here is a [NPM Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-multilevel-menu) and [Github Link](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu), the documentation is very sweet and simple.

Just in case, if you wanna see more examples, I have a [demo](https://multilevel-menu-demo.web.app/) for you and this is the [Github Repo](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu-demo) of the demo.

If something doesn't work for you, and you still wanna use this plugin, then [create an issue](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu/issues) here I'll help you out.

P.S. it works in IE11 as well.

Thanks